# OpenVPN ifconfig-ipv6 in TAP mode

Tags: openvpn, ipv6

I want to set up IPv6 address on my OpenVPN server operating in TAP mode.

According to documentation, ifconfig expects two parameters: `l` and `rn`. For TAP devices, `l` is local address, `rn` is netmask.

It works fine with IPv4: e.g. `ifconfig 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0`.

I tried to give it IPv4-like netmask, which is something not really used in IPv6, but I gave it a try. OpenVPN accepted this syntax, but no IP appeared on the interface:

```
ifconfig-ipv6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:2::1 ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:: # no address on the iface
```

Apparently, this commit [this commit](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/commit/c55e9562d64f381ba46b83a02503f6239e23d3ef) should've implemented prefix length syntax in OpenVPN. It didn't accept single argument, complained that the second one is missing. I tried various dummy arguments, like `::`. The server accepted them, but, again, the interface got no address.

```
ifconfig-ipv6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:2::1/64 # complains
ifconfig-ipv6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:2::1/64 :: # no address on the iface
```

Comment: Did you try `ifconfig-ipv6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:2::1 64`?

Comment: Just tried it, OpenVPN rejected this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, [this question has been posted on mailing lists earlier](http://sourceforge.net/p/openvpn/mailman/message/27629927/).

The correct syntax is indeed `ifconfig-ipv6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:2::1/64 ::`, but you also need to set `tun-ipv6` (even if you're using TAP mode, which is pretty confusing).

However, as of at least OpenVPN 2.3.4, it won't work unless you have IPv4 address specified with `ifconfig`. Might be a bug, or I'm missing something else.